# Doxygen is not showing static functions parameters

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm new to doxygen so this is probably going to be easy for you but I couldn't find any answer on the net.

I've the following `static` function which is declared in `file.hh` as:

```
static inline void fun (int a, int b);
```

And its definition is the following and is writen in `file.cc`:

```
/*! \brief Brief description of the function
   \param[in] a first parameter
   \param[in] b second parameter
*/
static inline void fun (int a, int b){
    printf("Hello World %d, %d!\n", a, b);
}
```

My Doxyfile is the following:

```
 # Doxyfile 1.8.14

 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Project related configuration options
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
 PROJECT_NAME           = LabRoboticsProject
 PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
 PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
 PROJECT_LOGO           = 
 OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = "doc"
 CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
 ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
 OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
 BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
 REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
 ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                          "The $name widget" \
                          "The $name file" \
                          is \
                          provides \
                          specifies \
                          contains \
                          represents \
                          a \
                          an \
                          the
 ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
 INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
 FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
 STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
 STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
 SHORT_NAMES            = NO
 JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
 QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
 MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
 INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
 SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
 TAB_SIZE               = 4
 ALIASES                = 
 TCL_SUBST              = 
 OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
 OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
 OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
 OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
 EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
 MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
 TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
 AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
 BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
 CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
 SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
 IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
 DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
 GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
 SUBGROUPING            = YES
 INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
 INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
 TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
 LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Build related configuration options
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
 EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
 EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
 EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
 EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
 EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
 EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
 HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
 HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
 HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
 HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
 INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
 CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
 HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
 HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
 SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
 SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
 FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
 INLINE_INFO            = YES
 SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
 SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
 SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
 SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
 SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
 STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
 GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
 GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
 GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
 GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
 ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
 MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
 SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
 SHOW_FILES             = YES
 SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
 FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
 LAYOUT_FILE            = 
 CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 QUIET                  = NO
 WARNINGS               = YES
 WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
 WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
 WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
 WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
 WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
 WARN_LOGFILE           = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the input files
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 INPUT                  = "src"
 INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
 FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                          *.cc \
                          *.cxx \
                          *.cpp \
                          *.c++ \
                          *.h \
                          *.hh \
                          *.hxx \
                          *.hpp \
                          *.h++ \
                          *.py \
                          *.pyw 
 RECURSIVE              = YES
 EXCLUDE                = 
 EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
 EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
 EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
 EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
 EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
 EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
 IMAGE_PATH             = 
 INPUT_FILTER           = 
 FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
 FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
 FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
 USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to source browsing
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
 INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
 STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
 REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
 REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
 REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
 SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
 USE_HTAGS              = NO
 VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
 CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
 CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
 CLANG_COMPILATION_DATABASE_PATH= 0
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
 COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
 IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the HTML output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_HTML          = YES
 HTML_OUTPUT            = html
 HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
 HTML_HEADER            = 
 HTML_FOOTER            = 
 HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
 HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
 HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
 HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
 HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
 HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
 HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
 HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
 HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
 HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
 GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
 DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
 DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
 DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
 DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
 GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
 CHM_FILE               = 
 HHC_LOCATION           = 
 GENERATE_CHI           = NO
 CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
 BINARY_TOC             = NO
 TOC_EXPAND             = NO
 GENERATE_QHP           = NO
 QCH_FILE               = 
 QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
 QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
 QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
 QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
 QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
 QHG_LOCATION           = 
 GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
 ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
 DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
 GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
 ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
 TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
 EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
 FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
 FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
 USE_MATHJAX            = NO
 MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
 MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/
 MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
 MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
 SEARCHENGINE           = YES
 SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
 EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
 SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
 SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
 EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
 EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
 LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
 LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
 MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
 COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
 PAPER_TYPE             = a4
 EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
 LATEX_HEADER           = 
 LATEX_FOOTER           = 
 LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
 LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
 PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
 USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
 LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
 LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
 LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
 LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
 LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the RTF output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_RTF           = NO
 RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
 COMPACT_RTF            = NO
 RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
 RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
 RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
 RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the man page output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_MAN           = NO
 MAN_OUTPUT             = man
 MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
 MAN_SUBDIR             = 
 MAN_LINKS              = NO
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the XML output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_XML           = NO
 XML_OUTPUT             = xml
 XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
 DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
 DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the Perl module output
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
 PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
 PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
 PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the preprocessor
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
 MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
 EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
 SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
 INCLUDE_PATH           = 
 INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
 PREDEFINED             = 
 EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
 SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to external references
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TAGFILES               = 
 GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
 ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
 EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
 EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
 PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to the dot tool
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
 MSCGEN_PATH            = 
 DIA_PATH               = 
 HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
 HAVE_DOT               = YES
 DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
 DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
 DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
 DOT_FONTPATH           = 
 CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
 COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
 GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
 UML_LOOK               = NO
 UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
 TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
 INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
 INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
 CALL_GRAPH             = NO
 CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
 GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
 DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
 DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
 INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
 DOT_PATH               = /usr/bin/dot
 DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
 MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
 DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
 PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = 
 PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      = 
 PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = 
 DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
 MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
 DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
 DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
 GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
 DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

When I run `doxygen` it finds and insert the static function inside the documentation, but it doesn't write anything of the description I gave. So the output is the following one:

[image]

While I would like something more like this:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not causing your problems, but there is a small error in your Doxyfile. After the `*.pyw` theer shouldn't be a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

A doxygen is in this case `/**` and not the standard C comment `/*`

See also http://doxygen.org/manual/docblocks.html#cppblock

The `cc` file inherits the documentation from the `hh` file but not the other way around! and both files are listed / shown in the overviews so one need to look in the `cc` file documentation.

Note further that the command is not `\parm` but `\param`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change that. And also the \ after .pyw is due to a change in the list and I forget to remove it, providing now. Although even with this corrections, the problem remains.

Comment: With the `file.cc` documentation I see the documentation. The `cc` file inherits the documentation from the `hh` file but not the other way around. Did you see my small edit regarding `\arm` / `\param`? Do you ret any warnings?

Comment: Nope no warning and if I try to remove static everything works fine

Comment: Strange as I do see the documentation: .../doc/html/file_8cc.html

Comment: The file exists, the problem is that it doesn't show the description and the parameters documentation I wrote for the static functions

Comment: Did you look in the file "../doc/html/file_8hh.html" or in the file "../doc/html/file_8cc.html", I see it in the later.

Comment: Oh my God! I didn't know there was any difference between the two of them! Thank you very much! I was just looking at the wrong file.